# change (CloudOTP) Sender name to any name that I want

Tags: firebase, onesignal

I searched everthing but Can't find what I'm looking for, I want to change sender name which is (CloudOTP) to my application name, or anything like that, is there a way for that please?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mr.Mark, unfortunately there seems there is no way to change the (Senders Name)

Comment: is there a way to change the APPNAME? when it says (code..) is your vertification code for (I want to change the name is displayed here cause it is firebase blah blah blah).